# Access Message Manager from phtml

Tags: magento2, template

`vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php` set in session messages like

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(
    __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
);
$this->_redirect('contact/index');
```

How do I access these messages in phtml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use dependency injection in order to load message manager in your block.

```
protected $messageManager;

public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    array $data = [])
{
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Then you can implement new method getMessages in the same block which will retrieve recent messages from manager.

```
public function getMessages()
{
    $messages = array();
    $collection = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
    if ($collection && $collection->getItems()) {
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $message) {
            $messages[] = $message->getText();
        }
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

And finally you can call method getMessages in block template.

```
<?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()): ?>
    <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
        <h1><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($message) ?></h1>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Magento 2.3.1